# how to fix Ambiguous occurrence error in Haskell

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I have wrote one function which has a signature of

```
sort :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

which gives me an error of

> Ambiguous occurrence ‘sort’

I know there is already a built-in function called sort in

> import Data.List

How can i fix this issue while keeping the same type signature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try

```
import Data.List hiding (sort)
```

This will prevent `Data.List.sort` from being imported, leaving you free to define your own function called `sort`.

If you want to be able to use `Data.List.sort` in addition to your own, also add the line

```
import qualified Data.List
```

or

```
import qualified Data.List as L
```

This allows you to to access the library function as `Data.List.sort` or `L.sort`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. but what if i want to use the built-in sort function as well in the same file while having my own type signature 'sort' function?

Comment: @USERSFU Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try qualifying the name:

```
module Foo where

import Data.List as L
```

Then, to refer to the library `sort`, use `L.sort`. For the user-defined sort, use `Foo.sort` instead.